# Organizing repetitive code with Visual Studio solutions

Tags: version-control, tfs

My team creates a lot of one-off web forms. Most of these forms just send an e-mail, and a few do a simple database write.

Right now, each form lives in its own separate solution in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. That means we have close to 100 different form projects, which makes it difficult to maintain consistency. Each form is unique in that the fields are different, but all of them do pretty much the same thing.

I'm looking to condense these somehow, and I could really use some guidance

- Should I try to create one solution file with all of our form projects in it? There isn't a lot of plumbing code, although I could create a few helper classes to help with e-mail formatting and such. It would be very helpful to be able to share CSS, JavaScript, controls and images across projects.
- Given that we're a Microsoft shop, are there any tangible benefits to going with something like MVC over Webforms for this specific scenario? I am sold on the concept of MVC as a whole, but would it help me pull together a 15-field data collection form more efficiently if all that form does is send an e-mail? The form that got me thinking about this had a good bit of logic built in to show and hide fields based on the user's responses and seems like it would have been less efficient to use MVC and jQuery.

Comment: Sorry, guys. Posted this over at programmers.stackexchange.com and it got closed. Posted here, then it was reopened over there. Didn't mean to cross post.

Comment: For reference, the post on Programmers.SE: [How to organize repetitive code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37798/how-to-organize-repetitive-code). Definitely on-topic there.